# How do I change the default colormap for pyplot?

Tags: python, python-2.7, colormap

I would like to change the default colormap for pyplots from 'viridis' to 'Dark2'.

I tried:

changing the 'image.cmap' line in the matplotlibrc file

mpl.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'Dark2'

mpl.pyplot.set_cmap('Dark2')

pyplot.set_cmap('Dark2')

Somehow none of these attempts worked. I also tried restarting the kernel afterwards and also restartet spyder itself but nothing changed. Now Im out of ideas.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot

mpl.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'Dark2'
mpl.pyplot.set_cmap('Dark2')
pyplot.set_cmap('Dark2')
```

I am always ending up with the default colors of the viridis colormap which starts with a blueish color and 2nd on orange one. I would like to see the green color from Dark2 first and than the orange one.

Appreciate your help !

cheers, Gerrit

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `plt.set_cmap` works for your use case. Here are two options that should.

**Use Seaborn's helper:**

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_palette('Dark2')
```

**Use Maplotlib rcParams:**

```py
from cycler import cycler
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler('color', plt.get_cmap('Dark2').colors)
```

Comment: The solution "Use Maplotlib rcParams" seems very convoluted, but is the one thing that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use [matplotlib.pyplot.set_cmap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.set_cmap.html?highlight=set_cmap#matplotlib.pyplot.set_cmap) is the way to change the default colormap. If you run the code below, you should see the 'Dark2' colormap.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


plt.set_cmap('Dark2')

plt.imshow(np.random.random((20, 20)))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```